# Use ProtoBuff.Net to receive multiple types of Objects over Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, tcpclient, protobuf-net

I'm implementing a custom protocol that will be used by two apps to send various commands to each other (including file transfers i.e. large binary data chunks). After much deliberation, I think protobuff is the right serializer to use for this task. Serialization with protobuff-net seems pretty straight forward. The issue I'm having is trying to figure out how to do deserialize various objects on the receiving end, especially, when the data is coming off of the network/socket. And many times I probably won't even know whether I have the entire packet to deserialize yet and continuously calling TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix doesn't seem like the right approach. My concerns are:

1. How do I implement a scheme where I can figure out not only the message type but also the packet size. I can't just use sizeof(Message) because in case of binary chunks, the actual binary data could vary. Should I add a MessageLength field as the first member of the BaseMessage that all messages inherit from. Then first call TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix by specifying BaseMessage type, this will give me the actual length of the serialized Message, then I make sure the required number of bytes have been read. If they are, then I call TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix with the actual MessageType? Any other way of doing this?
2. I saw some examples of TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix and it requires some kind of a lookup table that needs to be passed in. In my case the types of messages will easily cross 50 and grow as the app matures. Implementing a lookup table and keeping track of all the message types seems like a bad idea. Is there an alternative option that will allow the code to automatically deserialize various objects types coming off the socket?

Comment: *And many times I probably won't even know whether I have the entire packet to deserialize yet* - If you use TCP/IP that is handled for you.

Answer (score 1):

1) You could implement your objects so they define their type itself. Just create classes for each object. You can use inheritance if needed.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TransportObject1
{
...
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] data ...
}
```

If you want to inherit classes, simply make a normal C# inheritance and add something like [ProtoInclude(9, typeof(ChildClass))] to the **base** class.

Regarding your binary data, you could divide it in chunks by yourself (e.g. when reading from source stream etc) and create a transport object (class as shown above) with a byte[] member for the data. On the receiver side you could then receive these objects as any other object, process it and write it's data from the property to the Output stream.
Note: you don't need to worry about the packets you get to build up the "one big packet" that will be deserialized to your transport object (class). TCP handles this for you.
But you will need to care about ordering and processing data from the property (in which order you write it to the output stream on the receiver side). Because when you send multiple packets (chunks) at "the same time", the whole objects could be received in a different order. So you definitely want some kind of chunk ID in the objects.

2)
At some point when receiving data, you will need to specify which type of data you are receiving (which class represents the object).
Because from a socket you simply receive bytes and protocol buffers do not know anything about the type.
You could implement some kind of messages which have a fixed-size header (where the type is saved) and then read this header and determine the type of the object.
With the solution mentioned above, you then don't need any additional lookup tables when deserializing. Protobuf-net handles that for you.
Just use Protobuf-net's Deserialize(..) method with the type parameter you are expecting (by the type set in your message header).
You need that because protocol buffers does not save any information about the types in a object. The type is purely defined by the type you are expecting to be deserialized.
If you want some kind of auto-type mapping, you will need to use another protocol that serializes and deserializes information about the object type.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've used protobuf is with the TcpClient. After you establish a connection and have a TcpClient you can use the GetStream() method to get the handle on a blocking stream. The simple way to handle this is basically:

```
    while (true)
                {

                    var  datapacket =  Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T>(tcpStream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
     if (datapacket == null) break;//stream is done
//do somthing with the object here
                  }
```

The read will block until the protobuf gets enough data to deserialize an object